# Can I re-write this layout better?

Tags: html, layout

I feel like I am not writing this correctly and this is my first layout in this nature.
I have a site that has several backgrounds that go across the whole screen. The inner containers are 960 pixels and then centered.

The only problem is every section with a different background needs its own outer and inner div.

*Dabblet* 
http://dabblet.com/gist/2920465

[image]
     
       
         Foo

```
 <section class="hero">
   <div class="hero-container">
   Hero content  
   </div>
 </section>


 <section class="popular">
   <div class="popular-container">
   Header content  
   </div>
 </section>

 <div class="main">
   <div class="main-container">
     Main content
   </div>
 </div>

 <footer>
   <div class="footer-container">
     Footer content
   </div>
 </footer>
```

Comment: Doesn't look bad to me. The css could use a little work, and I try to stay away from defining dimensions in terms of pixels, but the layout is pretty normal.

Comment: Use `code` section instead of images, and provide starting dabblet point to improvement on [dabblet.com](http://dabblet.com/)

Comment: I just updated it with a dabblet.
I can't get the code section above to fully display, it's all indented 5 spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far the code looks ok. It's too simple to go wrong. Only thing for now i would change is the 5 classes

```
.header-container,
.hero-container,
.popular-container,
.main-container,
.footer-container
```

merge into one class `inner-section-container` and apply this class to the corresponding elemnts instead, as *for now* you do for all this classes the same thing.

Comment: Ooooh. Yes, I figured there was an easier way. This makes sense. Then I can still write my css like  .main .widget {} and all is well.
Cheers!